# Find element where sibling child has text

Tags: xpath, playwright

I have such a div:

```html
<div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c66-377">
   <mat-select _ngcontent-dgg-c495="" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-haspopup="true" class="mat-select ng-tns-c69-378 ng-tns-c66-377 ng-star-inserted" aria-labelledby="mat-form-field-label-339 mat-select-value-217" id="mat-select-216" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false">
      <div cdk-overlay-origin="" class="mat-select-trigger ng-tns-c69-378">
         <div class="mat-select-value ng-tns-c69-378" id="mat-select-value-217">
            <!---->
            <span class="mat-select-value-text ng-tns-c69-378 ng-star-inserted" style="">
               <span class="mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c69-378 ng-star-inserted">Delivery Correction</span><!----><!---->
            </span>
            <!---->
         </div>
         <div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper ng-tns-c69-378">
            <div class="mat-select-arrow ng-tns-c69-378"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!---->
   </mat-select>
   <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c66-377">
      <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c66-377 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-339" for="mat-select-216" aria-owns="mat-select-216" style="">
         <!---->
         <mat-label _ngcontent-dgg-c495="" class="ng-tns-c66-377 ng-star-inserted">Adjustment Reason</mat-label>
         <!----><!---->
      </label>
      <!---->
   </span>
</div>
```

I need to get a mat-select by looking at mat-label text().
Tried playing with following, following-sibling, descendant but without any success.
Working solution for me is: `//mat-label[text()='Adjustment Reason']/ancestor::node()[3]/mat-select`, but I don't like using ancestors or parents, as it's not a robust solution.

How can I improve this path?

P.S.
Replaced image with a snippet.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Generally, when asking "how can I improve this selector", it's important to show full page context. Sometimes, part of the markup you're ignoring and assume to be unimportant would provide a substantially easier hook into achieving whatever result you want. Always provide [full context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: I totally agree with @ggorlen on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```xml
//*[.//mat-label='Adjustment Reason']/mat-select
```

Essentially I'm selecting the `div` (or other parent element of `mat-select`) based on there being a descendant `mat-label` with a value of `Adjustment Reason`.

It might be a little more performant if we first check to see if the element has a child `mat-select`:

```xml
//*[mat-select][.//mat-label='Adjustment Reason']/mat-select
```

Comment: Thanks, that works and is clean enough for our use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [parent element locator](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#parent-element-locator).

```
const child = page.getByText('Adjustment Reason');
const parent = page.locator('mat-select').filter({ has: child });
```

Comment: We use .xml files to store selectors and just pass strings to Playwright's Page.Locator.
Any idea how this selector would look like as a plain string?

Comment: @Prox then you are simply not utilizing playwright full potential in terms of locator features and relying on plain css/xpath.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** (after new example in question)

You will need this XPath:

```
//mat-select[following-sibling::*[1][self::span]/label/mat-label/text()='Adjustment Reason']
```

This will select only if the  mat-select has a direct `following -sibling` with that `mat-label`

Comment: Sadly none of them works.

Comment: @Prox - That's because `mat-label` is not a descendant of `mat-select`. Your screenshot is a little bit deceiving. That's why it's always better to add the actual markup instead of a screenshot. Otherwise we can't test our suggestions without a lot of extra work.

Comment: @Prox: Your example has changed: is this really the actual content?

Answer (score 0):

```
//mat-select[preceding-sibling::span/mat-select-value-text/span[text()='Adjustment Reason']]
```

This xpath filters the selection to only include  elements that have a preceding sibling  containing a  with the text "Adjustment Reason."